# How to update value when moving row to another table

Tags: php, sql, field, insert-update

I have 2 tables:

> Table1
>   Table2

When I move a row from table1 to table2, I also want to update the datetime field and 1 more field. 
Say both table have identical column like this:

> id
>   shipped_by
>   datetime
>   other_column

I have the following sql line, but it is not working of course. But I want to have it something like that.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table2
          SELECT * FROM table1
          WHERE id = '$id' UPDATE table2
          SET shipped_by='$shipped_by', datetime='$datetime'";
```

The variable `$shipped_by` selects the userid, and `$datetime` date from now.

Can anyone help me with this sql code to make it work? I cannot figure it out.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To insert data form `table1` with some column data modified can be done with `insert` and `select` without `update`.. `select *` should be used here, each column must be listed except for modified ones..

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table2
          SELECT id, '$shipped_by', '$datetime', other_column FROM table1
          WHERE id = '$id'";
```